# ParserError while parsing a large txt file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file, parsing, txt

I am trying to parse a large .txt file with Pandas. The file is 1.6 GB in size. You can download the file [here](https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/allCountries.zip) (it is a GeoNames database dump of all countries and settlements).

In regard to loading and parsing the file in Pandas, I consulted the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509435/how-to-read-txt-in-pandas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas) and this is what I have in code:

```
import pandas as pd

for chunk in pd.read_csv(
    "allCountries.txt",
    header=None,
    engine="python",
    sep=r"\s{1,}",
    names=[
        "geonameid",
        "name",
        "asciiname",
        "alternatenames",
        "latitude",
        "longitude",
        "feature class",
        "feature code",
        "country code",
        "cc2",
        "admin1 code",
        "admin2 code",
        "admin3 code",
        "admin4 code",
        "population",
        "elevation",
        "dem",
        "timezone",
        "modification date",
    ],
    chunksize=1000,
):
    print(chunk[0])  # just printing out the first row
```

If I run the code above, I get the following error:

> ParserError: Expected 20 fields in line 1, saw 25. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

I don't know what is going wrong here. **Can someone tell me what is going wrong and how do I fix it?**

Comment: perhaps the single quote is creating problem

Comment: Please add the couple first lines of the file as a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the first 10 lines of the file with LibreOffice and using tab as delimiter worked fine

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

for chunk in pd.read_csv(
    'allCountries.txt',
    header=None,
    engine="python",
    sep="\t",
    names=[
        "geonameid",
        "name",
        "asciiname",
        "alternatenames",
        "latitude",
        "longitude",
        "feature class",
        "feature code",
        "country code",
        "cc2",
        "admin1 code",
        "admin2 code",
        "admin3 code",
        "admin4 code",
        "population",
        "elevation",
        "dem",
        "timezone",
        "modification date",
    ],
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
    chunksize=1000
):
    print(chunk.iloc[0])  # just printing out the first row
```

The file also contains characters ' and ", which pandas by default assumes to be used for quoting and that caused errors but setting quoting to QUOTE_NONE fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter was wrong, since you have spaces in one column (names):

> 2986043   Pic de Font Blanca  Pic de Font Blanca  Pic de Font Blanca,Pic du Port  42.64991    1.53335 T   PK  AD      00              0       2860    Europe/Andorra  2014-11-05

It got parsed wrong.

This code works for me:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(
    "allCountries.txt",
    header=None,
    engine="python",
    sep=r"\t+",
    names=[
        "geonameid",
        "name",
        "asciiname",
        "alternatenames",
        "latitude",
        "longitude",
        "feature class",
        "feature code",
        "country code",
        "cc2",
        "admin1 code",
        "admin2 code",
        "admin3 code",
        "admin4 code",
        "population",
        "elevation",
        "dem",
        "timezone",
        "modification date",
    ],
    chunksize=1000,
):
    print(chunk)
```